# AbstractMethodError when mixing in trait nested in object - only when compiled and imported

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

Consider the following code:

```
object Impls {
  trait ConcreteImpl {
    type Foo = Int
    def foo = 1
  }
}

trait Base {
  type Foo
  def foo: Foo
}
```

I am interested in the expression

```
(new Base with Impls.ConcreteImpl).foo
```

When I paste the above code in the REPL, or run it in a worksheet, and then try the expression -- no problem, it prints `res0: Int = 1`, as expected.

When I put the code in a file, compile it with `scalac`, and then use the compiled class files from the REPL in the same directory, I get the same result.

*However*, when I use the compiled files, and then say from the REPL

```
import Impls._
(new Base with ConcreteImpl).foo
```

it throws

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: $anon$1.foo()I
```

If I paste all code in the REPL, and use the import variant, this does *not* happen.

What is happening here? Is this even expected behaviour? If relevant, I am using

```
Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clearly a bug.

If you:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: $line13.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1.foo()I
  ... 33 elided

scala> :javap -p $line13.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1
Compiled from "<console>"
public final class $line13.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1 implements p.Base,p.Impls$ConcreteImpl {
  public java.lang.Object foo();
  public $line13.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1();
}
```

It doesn't have a foo with result type Int.

Offhand, I can't imagine the difference in the REPL, but we're about to watch a movie... You can try it in Ammonite, however.

Most such bugs are due to the fact that REPL is a resident compiler, but it's not obvious how that affects compilation with existing class files.

Edit:

It works the first time using fully-qualified names, but then after exhibiting the failure, fully-qualified fails again.

```
scala> (new p.Base with p.Impls.ConcreteImpl).foo // show
//works
res0: Int = 1

scala> import p._
import p._

scala> import Impls._
import Impls._

scala> (new Base with ConcreteImpl).foo // show
// fails
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: $anon$1.foo()I
  ... 33 elided

scala> (new p.Base with p.Impls.ConcreteImpl).foo // show
// also fails
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: $anon$1.foo()I
  ... 33 elided
```

That's clearly a resident compiler bug. (The classes are in package p here.)

Edit: Actually [SI-9689](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9689).

Comment: Since IDEs tend to use resident compilers, you will likely come across the issue in an IDE as well.