# Mapping over HList raises AbstractMethodError

Tags: scala, runtime-error, read-eval-print-loop, shapeless

I am trying a `shapeless` example in REPL and getting a runtime error:

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import shapeless.poly._
import shapeless.poly._

scala> object choose extends (Set ~> Option) {
     |   def apply[T](set: Set[T]) = set.headOption
     | }
defined object choose

scala> val sets = Set(1) :: Set(0) :: HNil
sets: shapeless.::[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int],shapeless.::[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int],shapeless.HNil]] = Set(1) :: Set(0) :: HNil

scala> sets map choose
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: choose$.caseUniv()Lshapeless/PolyDefns$Case;
  ... 42 elided
```

Do you know why it doesn't work and how to fix it ?

Comment: I got the same error when trying from the REPL, but it worked when trying it in Intellij. This one is a bit weird.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9689 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698560/abstractmethoderror-when-mixing-in-trait-nested-in-object-only-when-compiled-a

Comment: @DenisRosca They say it's a bug in REPL (see https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless/archives/2016/02/28). The workaround is using `:paste`. Tried `:paste` and it's working.

Comment: hmm good to know.